# Sorting of dynamically computed values using Spring Pageable

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private OffsetDateTime startTime;
    private OffsetDateTime endTime;
    private Long duration;
    
    public void setDuration() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(startTime) && Objects.nonNull(endTime)) {
            duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toSeconds();
        }
    }
}
```

It represents some event in the system that may last for some time. When new entity is created, `startTime` is set to `OffsetDateTime.now()`. `duration` property is set when event is finished and `endTime` is set.

When `Event` entities are fetched, `duration` is dynamically computed as `Duration.between(startTime, OffsetDateTime.now()).toSeconds()`.

I am trying to fetch `Event` entities using `Specification` and `Pageable` object in order to sort objects easily:

```
eventRepository.findAll(Specification, Pageable)
```

As you can imagine, sorting does not work for the events that are not finished (as `duration` in DB is set to `null`). Are there any possibilities to somehow set default value of a property while fetching it from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `@Formula("coalesce(duration, 0)") int durationForSort;` field and sort by that if you want this.